# how to use number of rounds on Nutchx2

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I have the same problem. I use just this command for whole process:

```
crawl urls/ucuzcumSeed.txt ucuzcum http://localhost:8983/solr/ucuzcum/ 10

crawl <seedDir> <crawlID> [<solrUrl>] <numberOfRounds>
```

By the way I'm using 2.3.1 version of Nutch and 5.2.1 version of Solr. The problem is that I cannot fetch whole web site for just this command. I suppose numberofRounds parameter doesnt work. At first run nutch just find 1 url for fetch and generate and parse it. After at the second step it can get more urls. In this case, this means nutch stops in the end of the first iteration. But it should continue according to my command. What should I do to crawl a whole website with nutch?

nutch-site.xml :

```
<property>
        <name>http.agent.name</name>
        <value>MerveCrawler</value>
    </property>

 <property>
        <name>storage.data.store.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore</value>
        <description>Default class for storing data</description>
    </property>

 <property>
        <name>plugin.includes</name>
        <value>protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|index-(basic|more)|query-(basic|site|url|lang)|indexer-solr|nutch-extensionpoints|protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-rege$
    </property>

<property>
    <name>http.content.limit</name>
    <value>-1</value><!-- No limit -->
    <description>The length limit for downloaded content using the http://
      protocol, in bytes. If this value is nonnegative (>=0), content longer
      than it will be truncated; otherwise, no truncation at all. Do not
      confuse this setting with the file.content.limit setting.
    </description>
  </property>
<property>
  <name>fetcher.verbose</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>If true, fetcher will log more verbosely.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>db.max.outlinks.per.page</name>
  <value>100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</value>
  <description>The maximum number of outlinks that we'll process for a page.
  If this value is nonnegative (>=0), at most db.max.outlinks.per.page outlinks
  will be processed for a page; otherwise, all outlinks will be processed.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>If true, outlinks leading from a page to external hosts
  will be ignored. This is an effective way to limit the crawl to include
  only initially injected hosts, without creating complex URLFilters.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>db.ignore.internal.links</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>If true, when adding new links to a page, links from
  the same host are ignored.  This is an effective way to limit the
  size of the link database, keeping only the highest quality
  links.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fetcher.server.delay</name>
  <value>10</value>
  <description>The number of seconds the fetcher will delay between
   successive requests to the same server. Note that this might get
   overriden by a Crawl-Delay from a robots.txt and is used ONLY if
   fetcher.threads.per.queue is set to 1.
   </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>file.content.limit</name>
  <value>-1</value>
  <description>The length limit for downloaded content using the file
   protocol, in bytes. If this value is nonnegative (>=0), content longer
   than it will be truncated; otherwise, no truncation at all. Do not
   confuse this setting with the http.content.limit setting.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>http.timeout</name>
  <value>100000000000000000000000000000000000</value>
  <description>The default network timeout, in milliseconds.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>http.timeout</name>
  <value>100000000000000000000000000000000000</value>
  <description>The default network timeout, in milliseconds.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>generate.max.count</name>
  <value>100000000</value>
  <description>The maximum number of urls in a single
  fetchlist.  -1 if unlimited. The urls are counted according
  to the value of the parameter generator.count.mode.
  </description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several reasons why the crawl might not get further e.g. robots.txt directives. Look at the logs and / or the content of the crawl table to get a better idea of what the problem might be

Comment: I checked whether there is robots.txt for that specific web site. But I coundt find anything any limitation. What could be the other reason that I cant crawl whole web site?